# Approving Pending Userpoints

Tags: userpoints

I'm developing a site that allows users to earn points based on site actions.  I have the site working for users and their points earned are going into a "pending" category.  The next step is that the points need to be administratively approved.

I was trying to find a way to have this action work through a page content or onclick button without having to go through config -> points -> moderation.

If anyone has any ideas or thoughts that have worked for them I'd love the help, I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey nit3ch, thanks for your answer, I couldn't get that to work but I got some rigged sql calls to work.  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

you can try [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to achieve this.
Create a event like "when a node is saved" and provide some condition if required and then action like grant/deduct user points. User points is integrated with rule.